# Alternative of FP_SEG and FP_OFF for converting pointer to linear address

Tags: c

On 16 bit dos machine there is options like FP_SEG and FP_OFF for converting a pointer to linear address but since these method no more exist on 32 bit compiler what are other function that can do same on 32 bit machine??

Comment: You know, right, that even if you have an absolute address to memory, you can't normally access it under Windows or Linux? You know how protected-mode memory works, right?

Comment: But using system call we can access!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're luckily not needed as 32-bit mode is unsegmented and hence the addresses are always linear (a simplification, but let's keep it simple).

EDIT: The first version was confusing let's try again.

In 16-bit segmented mode (I'm exclusively referring to legacy DOS programs here, it'll probably be similar for other 16-bit x86 OSes) addresses are given in a 32-bit format consisting of a16-bit segment and a 16-bit offset. These are combined to form a 20-bit linear address (This is where the infamous 640K barrier comes from, `2**20 = 1MB` and 384K are reserved for the system and bios leaving ~640K for user programs) by multiply the segment by `16 = 0x10` (equivalent to shifting left by 4) and adding the offset. I.e.: `linear = segment*0x10 + offset`.

This means that `2**12` segment:address type pointers will refer to the same linear address, so in general there is no way to obtain the 32-bit value used to form the linear address.

In old DOS programs that used far - segmented - pointers (as opposed to near pointers, which only contained an offset and implicitly used `ds` segment register) they were usually treated as 32-bit unsigned integer values where the 16 most significant bits were the segment and the 16 least significant bits the offset. This gives the following macro definitions for `FP_SEG` and `FP_OFF` (using the types from `stdint.h`):

```
#define FP_SEG(x) (uint16_t)((uint32_t)(x) >> 16) /* grab 16 most significant bits */ 
#define FP_OFF(x) (uint16_t)((uint32_t)(x)) /* grab 16 least significant bits */
```

To convert a 20-bit linear address to a segmented address you have many options (`2**12`). One way could be:

```
#define LIN_SEG(x) (uint16_t)(((uint32_t)(x)&0xf0000)>>4)
#define LIN_OFF(x) (uint16_t)((uint32_t)(x))
```

Finally a quick example of how it all works together:

Segmented address: `a = 0xA000:0x0123`
As 32-bit far pointer `b = 0xA0000123`
20-bit linear address: `c = 0xA0123`

```
FP_SEG(b) == 0xA000
FP_OFF(b) == 0x0123
LIN_SEG(c) = 0xA000
LIN_OFF(c) = 0x0123
```

Comment: 'uint16_t' undeclared (first use in this function) under gcc am getting this error now!!

Comment: @Amit `#include <stdint.h>` Are you really really sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: @xanartos i got i piece of code that is meant for 16 bit compiler ,am just trying to make comptible with 32 bit.